# LyX cannot instant preview / reconfigure. Frequent crash after the update macos 12.3.1

Tags: lyx, mac

I found that after the recent macos update(Monterey 12.3.1) I cannot use instant preview in LyX any more.

There are several other problems including unable to reconfigure, unable to rescan in Tools/TeX information, sudden change of fonts to Apple default fonts, and frequent crashes.

I list some of the error informations in the below:

1. When click reconfigure in Tools/Reconfigure it tells

*The system reconfiguration has failed.
Default textclass is used but LyX may
not be able to work properly.
Please reconfigure again if needed.*

Crash often follows.

2. When click Tools/TeX information/Rescan it tells

*The script `/Applications/LyX.app/Contents/Resources/scripts/TeXFiles.py' failed.*

I have tried to reinstall the LyX and MacTeX. It doesn't work. Also, after I reinstalled the MacTeX, I was not able to connect LyX to TeX using reconfigure. I had to navigate to the fold of LyX and run

```
sudo python configure.py
```

to reconfigure. It works! So now, I can still edit my files and build PDFs, but it is just annoying if these problems remain.

Comment: It turns out that it is related to the removal of Python 2 installation in Monterey 12.3. Please follow the link below to resolve this issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71591971/how-to-fix-zsh-command-not-found-python-error-macos-monterey-12-3-python